# TeamCity build number/version from constant in class

Tags: c#, teamcity, octopus-deploy

We want to make use of the Channels feature in Octopus Deploy, so when a release number contains "X.X.X.X-Beta" it should use the Beta channel.

Our problem is that we don't know how to set the version number in TeamCity, because it only allows hardcoded strings with some variables.
We don't want to set it it TeamCity, we want to use it in a class.
So we have a class called VersionInformation.cs with following content:

```
public static class VersionInformation
{
    public const string ProductVersion = "1.12.0.0";
    public const string ProductStage = "Beta";
}
```

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` files are containing following line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(VersionInformation.ProductVersion)]
```

Basically what we want to achieve:

1. Get changes from Visual Studio Online's TFS repository
2. TeamCity should read that class and set its own build version to "1.12.0.{buildNumber}-Beta"
3. TeamCity should create an Octopus release with that version

Our problem is, that we can't access our customer's TeamCity installation to change the versions there, so we are dependant on a solution which works on both sides (like that class).

Comment: If you take a look at the [Build Script Interaction documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) you can see that if you can trick your build (MSBuild perhaps?) to output a string to the console with the contents `##teamcity[buildNumber 'XYZ']` then you can control it, to get the `{buildNumber}` part you should inspect the environment variables which should contain the build number that TeamCity thinks this is, think it is simply called `BUILD_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the [Built Script Interaction](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) custom output from your build steps.

You need to trick your build, which I would assume is MSBuild, to output this to the standard console.

Basically, what you need to output should look like this:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber 'XYZ']
```

Where `XYZ` is the build number you want to output.

Here's a simple test batch file I created and attached to a TeamCity build configuration:

```
echo ##teamcity[buildNumber '1.2.0.%env.BUILD_NUMBER%-Beta']
```

After running it twice I got this:

[image: TeamCity screenshot after two builds]

Comment: We are using the "Visual Studio (.sln)" build step with OctoPack enabled. Do I need to change that?